# Состоит ли число из массива цифр

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив цифр (любой длины) и число.

Как проверить, что число содержит все цифры из массива?

Был вариант решать эту задачу путем деления числа на цифры с последующей проверкой, но этот вариант слишком громоздкий.

Можете предложить более быстрый способ ?

Comment: Всего цифр 10. Что может быть громоздкого в алгоритме?

Comment: да, но цифры могут повторяться, и таким образом размерность массива может быть любой.

Answer (score 5):

1. Создаем массив из 10 элементов, равных нулю. Назовем его `CNT`.
2. Заведем числовую переменную `K=1`
3. Бежим по входному массиву, увеличиваем CNT[цифра] на 1. Умножаем `K` на 10.
4. Закончили читать цифры. Делим `K` на 10  (т.к. один лишний раз умножили)
5. Убеждаемся, что `K`<=*ЧИСЛО* и `K*10`>*ЧИСЛО*(что бы лишней работы не делать). Т.е. проверяем, что число содержит столько же разрядов, сколько цифр в массиве.
6. В цикле делим *ЧИСЛО* на 10, вычитаем 1 из `CNT[остаток-от-деления]`. Если элемент в CNT стал меньше 0 - число не совпадает с массивом.
7. Так как мы знаем, что разрядность *ЧИСЛА* была равна длине массива и ни один из элементов `CNT` не стал отрицательным - значит все цифры были в нужном количестве !

Итого для работы нам надо один раз пройти по входному массиву и один раз по разрядам числа. Т.е. сложность порядка O(2n). В отличие от поиска каждой отдельной цифры перебором массива (даже если это встроенная функция), где сложность O(n*n)

Comment: хорошо, только один нюанс, скорее всего входное число будет строкой и выполнить сравнение будет проблематично. Длинную арифметику в вопросе не упоминали. Но ваш ответ легко перестраивается под строки сохраняя линейную сложность.

Answer (score 1):

Можно перевести число и цифры в строку/символы. И выполнить нужное количество раз поиск по строке.

Answer (score 1):

Можно выделить каждый разряд (видимо, десятичный - остаток от деления на 10) и проверить, входят ли получившиеся цифры в заданный массив.

Comment: Как раз делал таким способом.

Answer (score 1):

Пример на **PHP**:

```
function check($your_array, $your_number) {

    while ((int) $your_number !== 0) {

        $current = $your_number % 10;
        $your_number /= 10;

        if (!in_array($current, $your_array)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Примеры использования:**

```
if (check(array(1, 2, 3, 4), 1234)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Результат: **`success`**

```
if (check(array(1, 2, 3, 4), 123)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Результат: **`success`**

```
if (check(array(1, 2, 3, 4), 125)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Результат: **`fail`**

**ВАЖНО**: проверяется именно то, что все цифры есть в массиве. В массиве могут быть цифры, которых нет в числе. Обратное -- неверно.

**UPDATE**

А вот строгая проверка. Т.е. что все цифры массива есть в числе.

```
function check_strictly(& $your_array, $your_number) {

while ((int) $your_number !== 0) {

    $current = $your_number % 10;
    $your_number /= 10;

    foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $current) {
            unset($your_array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return count($your_array) === 0;
}

$your_array = array(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3);

if (check_strictly($your_array, 1234)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Результат: **`fail`**

Comment: Спасибо, делал именно таким образом. Буду проверять, почему у меня не верно. Скажите, а если речь идет о проверке не только состоит ли число из массива цифр, но и содержит ли число все цифры массива, как в этом случае можно решить задачу ?

Comment: @Drylozav, пожайлуста. Можно удалять элементы из массива, и посмотреть потом если в массиве элементы.

Comment: Благодарен Вам. Идею с удалением я как то не додумался рассмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Вам нужно по сути проверить вхождение одного множества в другое. Вы не указали конкретный язык, но во многих языках (или их стандартных библиотеках) есть понятие множества и операции над ним.

Теперь, ваш массив цифр нужно превратить в множество (например, завести пустое множество и добавлять цифры по одной). Набор цифр числа проще всего получить, переведя число в строковое представление и отбросив возможные «лишние» символы (например, минус). Строек можно легко разобрать на символы и упаковать во множество.

После получения двух множеств вопрос становится тривиальным: операция проверки вхождения обычно вам дана языком.

Comment: на множествах появится зависимость от реализации множества в языке, и можно попасть на то же квадратичное решение, только запакованное в типы и операции для множеств

Comment: @rdorn: Я больше заботился о семантике, а не об эффективности. В конце-концов, максимальная длина числа типа `int` меньше 20 (десятичных) цифр, так что любое решение всё равно O(1).

Comment: так то конечно, но по формулировке задачка больно похожа на учебную или олимпиадную начального уровня. Поэтому число запросто может оказаться N-значным, и крутись как хочешь.

Comment: @rdorn: Вызов принят! :) Окей, но во множестве всё равно не более десяти элементов, так что сравнение множеств всё равно O(1). Создание множества при _фиксированном_ N по идее тоже O(1). Единственное, что потенциально может быть квадратичным при плохой реализации множества — создание множества из массива цифр, т. к. на длину массива ограничений не было.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм может быть такой:

- 0). Получаем число и массив цифр.
- 1). Создаём массив цифр из заданного числа.
- 2). Для этих двух массивов создаём хеши, которые содержат количество вхождений заданной цифры.
- 3). Затем попарно сравниваем значения этих хешей, где ключом является число от 0 до 9.
- 4). Если сравнение не сработало, значит заданное число не удовлетворяет условию задачи.

**Реализация на perl**

```
sub check {
    # Шаг 0.
    my $number     = shift;
    my $digits_arr = shift;

    # Шаг 0.1: (опциональный - так как из условия не ясно, 
    # имеем ли мы дело только с натуральными числами или нет)
    #
    # Поэтому предварительно уберём лишний мусор из числа.
    # Например: -0.234 => 0234; -234.92 => 23492
    $number =~ s/[^\d]//ig;  

    # Шаг 1.
    my @number_digits = unpack('(a)*', $number);

    my %n;
    my %d;

    # Шаг 2.
    $n{$_}++ for @number_digits;
    $d{$_}++ for @{ $digits_arr };

    # Шаги 3 и 4.
    ($n{$_}//=0) == ($d{$_}//=0) or return for 0..9;

    return 1;
}

print check(-22.34999, [9,9,2,3,4,2,9]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**

### Проверка через replace

Для PHP есть решения "в оба конца", нечувствительные к повторам цифр в массиве цифр $digits и в числе $number, которые используют функции `preg_replace()` и `str_replace()`.

Если:

- число `$number` использовать как шаблон (строка "/[$number]/");
- в качестве строки замены взять пустую строку;
- массив цифр склеить в обрабатываемую строку (функция implode($digits)),

то функция `preg_replace()` удалит в обрабатываемой строке все символы шаблона,
т.е. *при наличии всех цифр из массива цифр в числе на выходе будет пустая строка*.

Если же

- использовать массив `$digit` в качестве массива поиска;
- в качестве строки замены использовать пустую строку;
- вместо обрабатываемой строки использовать число $number,

то функция `str_replace()` удалит все цифры массива поиска из обрабатываемой строки,
т.е. *при наличии в массиве цифр всех цифр числа на выходе будет пустая строка*.

Такой подход приводит к короткому и эффективному коду.

### Проверка с переводом числа в массив цифр

Поскольку количество цифр ограничено, то разница в программной сложности алгоритмов сводится к коэффициенту 10.
За этот коэффициент можно побороться так:

- с помощью функции str_split() или sscanf() преобразовать число в массив цифр;
- упорядочить массивы и выбросить повторы;
- сравнить массивы в параллельном проходе (если в одном из массивов нашлась меньшая цифра, то он точно не подмножество другого).

Однако тесты показали проигрыш в производительности.

### Программа:

```
define("N", 100000);
define("M", 11);
define("PR", 1);

function print_digits($text, $digits){
    print "$text [ ";
    foreach($digits as $dig){
        print"$dig ";
    }
    print "]";
}

function array_sort_unique($arr){
    sort($arr);
    $prev = null;
    foreach($arr as $key => $item){
        if($item === $prev){
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
        $prev = $item;
    }
    return array_values($arr);
}

function check_by_replace($number, $digits){
    $result1 = preg_replace("/[$number]/", "", implode($digits));
    $res1 = (empty($result1)) ? "&sub;" : "&nsub;";
    $result2 = str_replace($digits, "",  $number);
    $res2 = (empty($result2)) ? "&sub;" : "&nsub;";
    return[$res1, $res2];
}

function check_by_arrays($number, $digits){
    $arr_dig = array_sort_unique($digits);
    $str_num = (string)$number;
    $format = str_repeat("%1d", count($str_num));
    $arr_num = array_sort_unique(sscanf($str_num, $format));
    $res1 = "&sub;";
    $res2 = "&sub;";
    if($arr_dig !== $arr_num){
        $key_num = 0;
        $key_dig = 0;
        while(($key_num < count($arr_num)) && ($key_dig < count($arr_dig))){
            if($arr_num[$key_num] > $arr_dig[$key_dig]){
                $res1 = "&nsub;";
                $key_dig++;
            }elseif($arr_num[$key_num] < $arr_dig[$key_dig]){
                $res2 = "&nsub;";
                $key_num++;
            }else{
                $key_dig++;
                $key_num++;
            }   
        }   
    }
    return[$res1, $res2];
};

function comparison($number, $digits, $pr = 0){
    $replace_res = check_by_replace($number, $digits);
    $arrays_res = check_by_arrays($number, $digits);
    if($pr > 0){
        print_digits("<br><br>* check_by_replace: *", $digits);
        print_digits(" $replace_res[0] $number,&emsp;$number $replace_res[1]", $digits);
        print_digits("<br>* check_by_array: *", $digits);
        print_digits(" $arrays_res[0] $number,&emsp;$number $arrays_res[1]", $digits);
    }
}   
print"ПРОВЕРКА";

comparison(13579, [1, 9, 5], PR);
comparison(13579, [1, 9, 5, 2], PR);
comparison(13579, [9, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2], PR);
comparison(13579, [1, 9, 5, 9, 1], PR);
comparison(13579391, [1, 9, 5, 3, 2, 7], PR);

printf("<br><br>ТЕСТ БЫСТРОДЕЙСТВИЯ<br>%d сравнений по %d цифр<br>", (int)N, (int)M);

$test_dig = [];
$test_num = [];
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++){
    $dig = [];
    $num = [];
    for($j = 0; $j < M; $j++){
        $dig[] = mt_rand(0,9);
        $num[] = mt_rand(0,9);
    }
    $test_dig[] = $dig;
    $test_num[] = implode($num);
}

$time0 = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++){
    check_by_replace($test_num[$i], $test_dig[$i]);
}
$time1 = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++){
    check_by_arrays($test_num[$i], $test_dig[$i]);
}
$time2 = microtime(true);

printf("<br>check_by_replace: %.03f c", $time1 - $time0);
printf("<br>check_by_arrays: %.03f" c, $time2 - $time1);
```

### Результаты:

ПРОВЕРКА

```
* check_by_replace: * [ 1 9 5 ] ⊂ 13579, 13579 ⊄ [ 1 9 5 ]
* check_by_array: * [ 1 9 5 ] ⊂ 13579, 13579 ⊂ [ 1 9 5 ]

* check_by_replace: * [ 1 9 5 2 ] ⊄ 13579, 13579 ⊄ [ 1 9 5 2 ]
* check_by_array: * [ 1 9 5 2 ] ⊂ 13579, 13579 ⊂ [ 1 9 5 2 ]

* check_by_replace: * [ 9 1 7 5 3 2 ] ⊄ 13579, 13579 ⊂ [ 9 1 7 5 3 2 ]
* check_by_array: * [ 9 1 7 5 3 2 ] ⊂ 13579, 13579 ⊂ [ 9 1 7 5 3 2 ]

* check_by_replace: * [ 1 9 5 9 1 ] ⊂ 13579, 13579 ⊄ [ 1 9 5 9 1 ]
* check_by_array: * [ 1 9 5 9 1 ] ⊂ 13579, 13579 ⊂ [ 1 9 5 9 1 ]

* check_by_replace: * [ 1 9 5 3 2 7 ] ⊄ 13579391, 13579391 ⊂ [ 1 9 5 3 2 7 ]
* check_by_array: * [ 1 9 5 3 2 7 ] ⊂ 13579391, 13579391 ⊂ [ 1 9 5 3 2 7 ]

ТЕСТ БЫСТРОДЕЙСТВИЯ
100000 сравнений по 11 цифр

check_by_replace: 3.922 с
check_by_arrays: 10.482 с
```

Answer (score 0):

Если бы это был C++, я бы сделал так:

```
bool total(const char * s)
{
    unsigned short int flag = 0;
    unsigned short int mask[] = { 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0004, 0x0008,
                                  0x0010, 0x0020, 0x0040, 0x0080,
                                  0x0100, 0x0200 };
    for(;*s;++s)
    {
        if ((flag |= mask[*s - '0']) == 0x03FF ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Здесь, правда, я не проверяю, что все символы именно цифры.
Но смысл - выставляю битовый флаг, если в какой-то момент все цифры выставлены - ура, есть. Само собой, `O(n)`. Меньше быть не может в принципе...